# $2 \times 2$ matrix: find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find the eigenvectors and values of the matrix $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
-9 &1\cr
-6 &-4
\end{array}\right].$

I try taking $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ and I get $\lambda = 6$ or $7$.

Plugging in $\lambda = 6$, I get $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-15 &1\cr
-6 &-10
\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}
0 \cr
0 
\end{array}\right]$ and so the eigenvector is $\left[\begin{array}{c}
0 \cr
0 
\end{array}\right]$ but that doesn't make any sense since $\left[\begin{array}{c}
0 \cr
0 
\end{array}\right]$ can only be an eigenvector when $0$ is an eigvenvalue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The eigenvalues are $-6$ and $-7$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculation of the characteristic equation is wrong:
$$ \begin{vmatrix} -9-\lambda & 1 \\ -6 & -4-\lambda \end{vmatrix} = (9+\lambda)(4+\lambda)-(-6) = \lambda^2+13\lambda+42 = (\lambda+7)(\lambda+6). $$
Therefore the eigenvalues are $-6$ and $-7$, and you have to solve for $\lambda=-6$
$$ \begin{pmatrix} -3 & 1 \\ -6 & 2 \end{pmatrix} v = 0, $$
which is solved by $v = (1,3)$, for example. $\lambda=-7$ gives
$$ \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ -6 & 3 \end{pmatrix} v = 0, $$
which you can manage, I'm sure.

Comment: Thank you for the response but could you please spell out how you solved for $v = (1,3)$ given that $\lambda = -6$? All I get is that $v_1 = \dfrac{v_2}{3}$.

Comment: Well, that means that any solution of the form $(v_1,3v_1)$ is valid. I just chose a simple one. Remember that a constant multiple of an eigenvector is another eigenvector.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the issue I was having now.